# Extracting string with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup in python 3.4 as follows

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(URL), 'html.parser')

for fraction in soup.findAll("div", { "class" : "eventprice" }):
    print(fraction.get_text())
```

The data I am trying to extract from is as follows:

```
<div id="ip_selection983317834" class="eventprice">


                    1/2


        </div>
```

I've explored multiple options with fraction.get_div, changing attributes, what not. What's happening here?

Comment: Can you share the target URL?

Comment: What is the result you are getting and what is the url?

Comment: Try `print(fraction.text)`. That might work

Comment: http://sports.williamhill.com/bet/en-gb/betting/y/5/tm/0/Football.html is the URL. The id is actually id="ip_selection982952173price".

Sorry Terry, that doesn't work either.

Comment: That link seems to redirect me to the main page. Perhaps there needs to be some login details required on the website to access your link?

Comment: It's hardly storing a form submission in the cache? It directs me straight to todays matches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply switching to [`requests`](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) makes it work for me:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = "http://sports.williamhill.com/bet/en-gb/betting/y/5/tm/0/Football.html"
response = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

for fraction in soup.findAll("div", { "class" : "eventprice" }):
    print(fraction.get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
1/2
16/5
11/2
8/5
...
5/6
21/10
7/2
```

I'm guessing this is because of the default headers sent by `requests`. In my case they are:

```
{'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.3.0 CPython/2.7.6 Darwin/14.1.0'}
```